# input type="number" on mobile shrinks to according to max="x" attribute

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have an input defined like this with Bulma:

```
<div class="field is-horizontal">
  <div class="field-label is-normal">
    <label class="label">
      <span>Quantity</span>
      <sup class="has-text-danger">*</sup>
    </label>
  </div>  
  <div class="field-body">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input" max="4" min="1" placeholder="Enter the quantity" required type="number"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks as it should on desktop; that is it is expanded and fills the width:

[On desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyAn3.png)

But on mobile it shrinks a lot. Too much I would say. Despite there being ample space to fill on the width.

[On mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsGd4.png)

It seems that the `max="x"` attribute has something to do with it. Because when I remove `max="x"` it looks like on desktop again.
How to make it fill available width without removing `max="x"`?

Comment: Could you add the CSS, please?

Comment: It is Bulma CSS version 0.7.4 at https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/releases/tag/0.7.4.